# Htaccess does not redirect non-root pages

Tags: .htaccess

Case:

**www.domain.com** redirects to **domain.com**

**www.domain.com/somecategory** does not redirect to **domain.com/somecategory**.

The links on the page are relative, and this is causing problems with google as all www links are now duplicate content. Is there any way to fix this and force a non-www redirect on all WWW pages regardless of if it's root or not ?

htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=301,L]
```

i've also tried

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Have you searched the site? If yes: what is the specific issues you are having / where ar you stuck?

Comment: Yes i've searched the site. Specifically, my subdirectories are not redirecting to non-www if I link to them directly. They only redirect if coming through root.

Comment: I don't see how this is not a valid question at all. You have basically hundreds of threads detailing www to non-www or non-www to www, but none regarding this spesific question. Please elaborate on your flyby -1 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And it seems to be working.

Without the slash in the rewrite rule, I was redirected to `domain.compage` instead of `domain.com/page`

Comment: Yeah, it's a typo. The code you are using is actually in use on the site atm. I am leaning towards this not being a htaccess issue at all, but a problem with the PHP backend. I'm going to set this as the correct answer given that the problem is most likely not here. Thanks tho

Comment: Sent you a helprequest through the sectorseven contactform.

Comment: Replied. The only reason I can think of, is that the longer URL (with the path) is triggering another rule first. Try placing this rule first in the list. If it does not help, try removing unessential rules.